# Access DevOps API

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to invoke some DevOps API without success, I always get 401.

I've achieved a Personal Access Token just like documentation required, but it doesn't work anyway.

Sample code:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://azuredevops.{organization_name}.net/");

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "name.surname", "<PAT>")));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

var result = await client.GetAsync(...);
```

Please, note my url (it's http and it's the only one I know) -> http://azuredevops.{organization_name}.net/

And also note that I've tried both with name.surname and empty string passing PAT only.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, here is a sample code to list projects of a collection in Azure DevOps Server, where the `Uri` uses `http` and includes not only the server instance but also the collection name.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace ListProjects
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var MyPat = "xxxxx";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://aztfs2022/DefaultCollection/");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "name.surname", MyPat)));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

            //List Projects in a collection

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?api-version=7.0").Result;

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented));


            //Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]